# QEMU acting very weirdly

Tags: gpu, qemu, opengl

this is my first question on this website.
For a long time now I've wanted to make a virtual machine for gaming. Maybe not with a full single GPU pass through but I've wanted it to support OpenGL. It turned out to be a complete nightmare since I've really spent a lot of time on it. Previously I had an Nvidia GPU, so you got your answers right there. The graphics drivers are closed and with Nvidia being Nvidia it's impossible to do anything on Linux. But today I got an AMD card. RX 6650 XT to be more precise.

The first thing I did was recompiling my whole system since I use Gentoo. It took 12h and the first thing I did after updating was rebooting and checking if this virtual machine finally works. I wanted to have OpenGL so in virt-manager I have Spice graphics with OpenGL on and virtio screen with 3d accel. To my surprise it still doesn't work. It says either "internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor" or "internal error: qemu unexpectedly closed the monitor". Maybe there's a different, simpler method. I'm open to any suggestions and I'll give any system info you ask for